# jquery add the values inside same div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello people Iam trying to add ,all the value found inside same div...

```
    <div id="price">20</div>
<div id="price">25</div>
<div id="price">10</div>
<div id="price">10</div>
<div id="price">5</div>
```

So in my output Iam supposed to get Total `value=70` .. I tried using `each` and `map` both did not work as expected...

```
  var total = 0;
  $( "#price" ).map(function() {

        var total + = Number($(this).val());

   }).get();
   console.log(total);
```

Iam getting an error `Unexpected token +=` same in case of `each` ,, any ways to fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got is due to spacing in between `+` and `=` opeator. also Ids should be unique, use class instead.try this:

**DOM:**

```
<div class="price">20</div>
<div class="price">25</div>
<div class="price">10</div>
<div class="price">10</div>
<div class="price">5</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var total = 0;
$( ".price" ).each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
console.log(total);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7uGy5/)**

This is not recommended but you can use attribute-value to target elements with same ids:

```
var total = 0;
$( "[id=price]" ).each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
console.log(total);
```

**[Demo with attribute-value](http://jsfiddle.net/NhZ55/)**

Comment: any other ways apart from changing the name into class?? can we use same attribute and perform same oprtion??

Comment: @Friend: i wont recommend using this approach but second one will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the practice of giving all those divs the same id is a bad one. You should instead give them each a class and try something like this:

```
var total = 0;
$('.price').each(function(e){
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Hope ,We need to add `total +`

Answer (score 0):

```
//    javascript solution
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")
var total = 0;
for(var i=0;i<div.length;i++){
    total+= parseInt(div[i].textContent)

}
alert(total)
```